# How to separate bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistical-test

I'm trying to plot a bar chart that represents a two way anova, but the bars are overlapping, does anyone know an easy way to plot a data set that way?

```
data <- structure(list(nozzle = c("XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", 
                                  "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", "XR", 
                                  "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", 
                                  "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", 
                                  "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR", "AIXR"), 
                       trat = c("Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", 
                                "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 12.8", 
                                "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", 
                                "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", 
                                "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34", 
                                "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 12.8", "Cle 34", 
                                "Cle 34", "Cle 34", "Cle 34"), 
                       adj = c("Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", 
                               "Without", "Without", "Without", "With", "With", "With", 
                               "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "Without", "Without", 
                               "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without", 
                               "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With"), 
                       dw1 = c(3.71, 5.87, 6.74, 1.65, 0.27, 0.4, 0.37, 0.34, 0.24, 0.28, 0.32, 
                               0.38, 0.39, 0.36, 0.32, 0.28, 8.24, 10.18, 11.59, 6.18, 0.2, 0.23, 
                               0.2, 0.31, 0.28, 0.25, 0.36, 0.27, 0.36, 0.37, 0.34, 0.19)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -32L), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data_sum <- summarySE(data,
                          measurevar="dw1",
                          groupvars=c("nozzle", "trat","adj"))

ggplot(data_sum,
       aes(x = as.factor(trat), y = dw1,group = as.factor(nozzle), fill = as.factor(adj),
           ymax=dw1+se, ymin=dw1-se))  +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour = "black", width = 0.2, show_guide = FALSE, position="dodge")  +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Presence of adjuvants" ,
                    values = c('grey80', 'grey30'),
                    labels = c("Without",
                               "With"))  +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=0.7),
                width=0.0, size=0.5, color="black")  +
  labs(x = "Treatment g.i.a. ha-¹",
       y = "Dry Mass (g)")  +
  theme_classic()+ facet_grid(nozzle ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

I expected something like that:

[image: expected]

But with two factors in the same plot and one common Y-axis.

Comment: Change to `facet_grid(. ~ nozzle, scales = "free_y")`. Will that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, it changed the position of the tab but it still has the overlapping bars, thank you.

Comment: Where is `summarySE` defined? It doesn't appear to be part of the base packages. Alternatively, you may wish to simply provide the output from `dput(data_sum)` rather than `dput(data)` + code for its summary, since the ggplot portion doesn't appear to make use of `data` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you need to use the function `dodge2` instead of `dodge`. See this [reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html). This is the code that can help you.

```
ggplot(data_sum ,aes( x = trat, y = dw1,  group = nozzle, fill = adj)) + 
geom_bar( colour = "black", width = 0.5, stat="identity",
         # Position dodge2 solve the overlapping problem
         # (padding) Add distance between bar in the same group
         position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.5)) + 
scale_fill_manual(name = "Presence of adjuvants",
                 values = c('grey80', 'grey30'),
                 labels = c("Without",
                            "With")) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = dw1 + se, ymin = dw1 - se),
             # Need to be consistent with bar position
             # (padding) Here it will control the width of
             # top and botton horizontal line. If you want
             # you can choose padding = 1 to not have those lines
             position = position_dodge2(padding = 1.3),
             # (width) Control the width of error_bar and
             # in this case has a side effect of shift the 
             # position of this error bar.
             # Then this width need to be the same of geom_bar
             width = 0.5, 
             size = 0.5,
             color="black")  +
labs(x = "Treatment g.i.a. ha-¹",
    y = "Dry Mass (g)") +
facet_grid(.  ~ nozzle, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]